Wrong alignement for environment marginfigure of package sidenotes
When redacting my PhD thesis, I found myself wanting to add a side-figure here and there to tell the reader that something is important. The idea is to put a figure inside the margin where needed. I thought that the package sidenotes and its marginfigure environment would be perfect for that. However, when I try it, the alignement is wrong on even pages.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mfrin}{\begin{marginfigure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{marginfigure}}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \mfrin{}\lipsum[1]
    
    \newpage
    
    \mfrin{} \lipsum[1]
        
\end{document}

While it works well on odd pages:

it fails miserably for even pages:

Is there a simple way to fix this? Alternatively, can you think of another way to perform the same task?

Edit 1: it seems that removing the \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} solves this issue. Any idea why? I think I'll be needing this package further on so removing it is not an option...
Edit 2: I added the showframe package as suggested by daleif, we can see - without the geometry package in order to better see it - that the figure on the even page is left aligned:

Using the following MWE, we can see that there is an issue with the side margins of the document when using geometry:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry} % <-- comment this out to make the issue disappear
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}

With geometry:

Without geometry:

I must admit that I'm rather confused. Should I report a bug to the geometry package maintainers?
Edit 3 (a.k.a. #ItsNotABugItsAFeature): as jlab explains in the accepted answer, it is a feature of the geometry package that can be addressed in several ways. A quick and dirty fix consists in redefining marginparwidth to a relatively small value (this may be acceptable if - like me - you only want to use the margin to put an icon here and there), i.e. with \usepackage[marginparwidth=80pt]{geometry}.

Try adding \usepackage{showframe} then it is easier to see the margins. Loading geometry sets different default margins. I think there is an option for it not to, haven't looked.

And I'm guessing yuo wanted the figure on page 2 to be up againgst the text. There you have to add something such that on even pages the contents of the margin figure is ragged left.

showframe is also a geometry package option.  IIRC, I used to get error messages trying to use the showframe package with geometry.

The geometry package always modifies the layout (except with the pass option, but it is then disabled). By default, it uses, for two-sided documents (from the manual, section 6.4) :

scale=0.7 (body is 0.7 × paper)
marginratio={2:3, 2:3} (2:3 for horizontal and vertical margins)
ignoreall (the header, footer, marginal notes are excluded when calculating the size of body.)

In your case, with ignoreall the margin notes are outside the paper. Use the option includemp or includeall :
\usepackage[includemp]{geometry}

or set a complete layout, including the marginal notes, using the geometry options (see manual, section 5).
By the way, no need to set the geometry a4paper option if you pass it the the class. Full example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[includemp]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mfrin}{\begin{marginfigure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{marginfigure}}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \mfrin{}\lipsum[1]

    \newpage

    \mfrin{} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}




Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I accepted it as it solves the issue and explains the ins and out. As for my problem, since I won't be using side margins for anything else than putting the said symbol here and there, I do not want to sacrifice too much space for the side margins (which is the case when using includemp as you suggest, IMHO). Thus I just specified marginparwidth=80pt as it allows enough space for my symbol without making the linewidth too small...
